# telegram bot Сделать кнопку назад

Tags: php, telegram

Очень нужен совет. Как правильно надо делать. Пишу телеграмм бот на php. Вопрос как правильно делать кнопку назад. Есть последовательный вывод информации Сперва введите имя затем возраст затем место работы. Как сделать что везде была кнопка назад и я мог перейти из введите возраст на введите имя.
Читал что надо делать автомат состояний. Но хотелось бы как то подробнее. Кто знает, подскажите. Буду очень признателен

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1: делаете кнопку "Назад" типа [inline](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton), в поле callback_data добавляете строку с данными (ограничение 64 байт), например "action=back&step=1".

Пользователь нажимает "Назад", бот отправляет запрос на ваш webhook, из ['callback_query']['data'] получаете эту строку, разбираете по переменным и понимаете, на какой этап нужно вернуться.

Более сложный вариант: хранить текущий этап для каждого пользователя в БД, каждый раз при отправке информации или нажатии кнопки "Назад" обновлять запись.

Comment: почему более сложный?) Наверное самое оптимальное решение это хранить всё в бд